# jQuery counter with increasing speed

Tags: jquery, counter

I'm trying to create a function where the user clicks a link (mousedown behaviour), either `<a href="#" id="down"> - </a>`or `<a href="#" id="up"> + </a>`.
Based on which one is clicked, the value in a div increases or decreases with 1: `<div id="counter">1</div>`

The minimum value is 1, maximum is 100. So far, no real problems. But...
... while the user keeps the link pressed, the number should first change once per 1000ms, after 7 iterations it should change to once per 500ms and after 5 more iterations it should change every 250ms **IF** the number can not be divided by 5, otherwise the speed 'stays' 500ms.

On release, the counter should stop immediately.

I hope this kind of makes sense, I don't really know where to start.

Thanks,
Knal

Comment: I would start with a function that implements the speed requirement.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/](https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/)

Comment: @MaxZoom  I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @TK Thanks, I've tried applying that to chindirala sampath's answer below, but no success...

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to detect click event on anchor tag then remove href attribute. For your requirement I think the below code helps.

```js
var currentValue = 1;
var totalNumberOfClicks = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#down").click(function(){
if(currentValue!=1)
currentValue--;
totalNumberOfClicks++;
handleLogic();
});

$("#up").click(function(){
if(currentValue!=100)
currentValue++
totalNumberOfClicks++;
handleLogic();
});
});

function handleLogic()
{
if(totalNumberOfClicks<=7)
{
  $("#counter").delay(1000).text(currentValue);
}
else if(totalNumberOfClicks<=12)
{
$("#counter").delay(500).text(currentValue);
}
else 
{
if(totalNumberOfClicks%5!=0)
$("#counter").delay(500).text(currentValue);
else
$("#counter").delay(250).text(currentValue);
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a style="cursor:pointer;font-size:20px;" id="down"> - </a> or <a style="cursor:pointer;font-size:20px;" id="up"> + </a>
<div id="counter">1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!

Maybe I haven't been completely clear on my goal: want to decrease and increase the number while the user has the link pressed. When he releases the number 'freezes' but timers (or intervals) are reset.

When I try to change your `click` to `mousedown` I still can't get it to work...